# Invoices kept in document with user information in no sql database is recommended?

Tags: database-design, nosql

**I have a application which has tenant details like**

```
{ 
"name" : "", 
"Address" : "" ,
...
Bills :[
     current : {"rent":"" ,"electricity":"" ,"date":""},
     previous : [{"rent":"" ,"electricity":"" ,"date":""}, 
                {"rent":"","electricity":"" ,"date":""}]
] 
}
```

**I have Bills of a tenant in the tenant document itself** , 
is this model recommended / acceptable ?

The reason would be silly , 
I thought since the scope of bill is only viewing and won't do any computations on bills , So keeping it in a separate document would be a extra work . So I kept in this tenant document itself .

So Keeping bills in this type of document is good or bad ?

If I get some clarity it would be nice , Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost always with databases, it depends on what you're going to *do* with the data *after* you're stored it.

How are you going to retrieve and process it?

If you only ever access this data by Tenant, then carrying a block of "stuff" around with each Tenant "document" is probably OK.
If you wanted to start querying and comparing bills across your tenants, though, this structure might be inefficient.

> ... won't do any computations on bills ...

Do you not have to summarise your rental income for your annual Tax Return?

That would mean pulling out any Current or Previous "rent" entries that fall within the last Tax Year - I suggest that might get just a bit *fiddly* with the data structure you have (and, although you've not shown any, the **Date** formats that you're using).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phill , I would use these bills just for viewing (like to see my previous bills ) ,in Bill only date and rent is my entry , every other attributes are dynamically added by the owner . There won't be any tax or any computations . Also about the date format , I haven't decided it yet but mostly I would prefer milliseconds in long format .( If you have any suggestions plz do tell ).

Comment: If you're going to keep the [JSON] document format, I'd suggest a sortable Date format - "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffff".  That way, you'll dodge many of the basic difficulties when you start trying to do "Date" things with Character data, like showing them in [a different] order.  Date sorting semantics are different from character ones (unless you use a sortable format!).  Of course, this also means that you'll have to reformat these dates (in your Application) for display; only a few countries in the World use this format on a day to day basis.

Comment: Okay , I will use the sortable date format . Thanks !